# Why do this dates not match?

Tags: javascript

i have this code which works with dates:

```
let startDate = new Date(toolOrder.jsAppStartDate.getTime()); // clone date
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - Math.floor((days - 1) / 2)); // sub some days
console.log(toolOrder.jsAppStartDate); // Output: Date Thu Sep 21 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
console.log(toolOrder.jsAppStartDate.getTime()); // Output: 1695247200000
console.log("--------------");
for (let index = 0; index < days; index++)
{
    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(startDate.getTime());
    // ... some drawing code here ...
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1); // add one day
    if(startDate === toolOrder.jsAppStartDate) // check if start date reached
    {
        console.log("Dates match");
        startDate = new Date(toolOrder.jsAppEndDate.getTime());
    }
}
```

The output of the log before the loop is:

```
Date Thu Sep 21 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
1695247200000
---------------
```

The output from the loop is:

```
Date Mon Sep 18 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
1694988000000 
Date Tue Sep 19 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
1695074400000
Date Wed Sep 20 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
1695160800000
Date Thu Sep 21 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
1695247200000
Date Fri Sep 22 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
1695333600000
```

So even if the dates match in loop 3, the if condition is not true. It works when I use

```
if(startDate.getTime() === toolOrder.jsAppStartDate.getTime())
```

but I thought it should work without also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`===` compares **identity** so:

```
startDate === toolOrder.jsAppStartDate
```

Means: is `startDate` the same **object** [in memory] as `toolOrder.jsAppStartDate` which is not the case because `toolOrder.jsAppStartDate` is a *different* object and not the object referred to by the name `startDate`.

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) says this about the strict equality operator:

> If both operands **are objects**, return **true** only if they refer to the **same object**.

(emphasis mine)

```
if(startDate.getTime() === toolOrder.jsAppStartDate.getTime())
```

Works because you're now comparing numbers instead of objects.

The rule for the two operands being numbers is:

> Otherwise, compare the two operand's values:
>
> **Numbers must have the same numeric values.** +0 and -0 are considered to be the same value.

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) (emphasis mine)

Comment: Hi @marco-a, `getTime()` returns a number. I tried editing your answer but the edit queue was full.

Comment: @MehmetBaker Thank you, that slipped through. Wasn't really paying attention to what `getTime()` _exactly_ returns.

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the things where JS is not very straight forward, as you can compare dates with < and > even if they are not the same objects. Maybe the best thing is to add a compare and equal function to the date prototype and use that

Comment: @Thallius, if you've used `==` operator than type casting would happen and you wouldn't face this issue. `===` disables type casting during the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `Date` instances with each other when you're using the `===` operator. However, they are not the same instance. Each `new Date` creates a unique, new instance (unless the class constructor deliberately returns a previously created instance [for more info: [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)]).

When you are comparing each instance's `getTime()` result, you are comparing 2 primitive values (numbers in this case). Primitive values are not class instances; so `===` works like `==` with primitives.